# How to convert JSP to Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have problems with Thymeleaf and I don't know how can I do this.

```
<!-- chart.jsp-->
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

var dps = [[]];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Simple Column Chart with Index Labels"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
        //indexLabel: "{y}", //Shows y value on all Data Points
        indexLabelFontColor: "#5A5757",
        dataPoints: dps[0]
    }]
});

var xValue;
var yValue;
var indexLabel;

<c:forEach items="${dataPointsList}" var="dataPoints" varStatus="loop">
    <c:forEach items="${dataPoints}" var="dataPoint">
        xValue = parseInt("${dataPoint.x}");
        yValue = parseFloat("${dataPoint.y}");
        indexLabel = "${dataPoint.indexLabel}";
        dps[parseInt("${loop.index}")].push({
            x : xValue,
            y : yValue,
            indexLabel : indexLabel
        });
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>

chart.render();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have just started using Thymeleaf, and the JSP format does not work for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 6):

This answer does not cover all aspect of converting `jsp` to `thymeleaf` but should give you some direction.

1. You need to create a `html` file `chart.html` and save it under `src/main/resource/templates`
2. your `html` should start with

   `<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`
3. Your loop will change from

   `<c:forEach items="${dataPointsList}" var="dataPoints" varStatus="loop">`

   to `th:each="dataPoints:${dataPointsList}"`

   and `<c:forEach items="${dataPoints}" var="dataPoint">`

   to  `th:each="dataPoint:${dataPoints}"`
4. Take a look at [thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html). They have good documentation.